# Проверка поля ввода года через регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Поле, в которое вводится год, проверяется через регулярное выражение

```
 ^(0)$|^([1-9][0-9]*)$
```

оно проверяет, что вводится целое число. 
Как добавить в регулярное выражение проверку, чтобы вводились только 4 цифры?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3}$
```

Comment: а почему вы убрали первую часть выражения?

Comment: первая часть выражения отвечает за случай, когда число = 0

Answer (score 0):

`^\d{4}$` – исключительно 4 цифры.

Нули в начале на случай первого тысячелетия, `^-?\d{4}$` на случай до н.э. (мало ли).